# TFS Merge future code to previous release branch

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

We are in the middle of a complex system migration, and are on a three branch system - Feature, Main, and Release.

We released our last feature branch by merging to main, fixing integration issues, then branching to release 3.00. This is now our current PROD and hotfix.

Following 3.00, a new feature branch was created.  We have merged the new feature to Main, resolved integration issues, and branched to release 3.01, our upcoming release.

Here now is the problem - release 3.00, our current production, was supposed to support employee discounts.  It does not.  The employee discount feature was developed in the new feature branch, merged through main, and branched into the upcoming release.

I need to merge future code into the past, and diagramming this has me looking like Doc Brown in BTTF2 where he's explaining the alternate time continuum.  I need to take the future and merge it to the past Marty (see my attached drawing).

All that to say, how can I merge code from a younger branch to an older branch?  I was going to post a drawing, but apparently I have to have a reputation before I can do that.  So here's a shared link to google drive:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw8tCgQHaBKMR2N5c1lZdEZIdkE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Now that's a fix to be in. The reality is you would likely be best re-implementing the feature on the older branch. You could maybe achieve a reverse feature integration if you have full unit tests going back to that older version. Otherwise you are looking at a line by line frankinMerge that you will be debugging forever.

My recommendation would be to go the re-implement route as the safest.